# Android M Custom Boot Image for Nexus 6

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, nexus6

I unpacked `boot.img` of **Android M for Nexus 6** using **Android Image Kitchen (AIK)** and then repacked it without any changes, then flashed the phone with the new boot.img. Ideally it should work but somehow the phone doesn't boots showing boot error ([img](http://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/moto-x-2013/92780d1384906685t-kitkat-crashed-my-moto-x-unrecoverable-android-error.jpg)).

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Can anyone suggest an alternative for it?

(For those who think why I am using the image without altering, well I made some changes in the boot.img which did not work, so while debugging I found that even if I do not make any changes to the img file, it doesn't works. Couldn't figure out the reason.)

I am using `fastboot` on `mac` to flash Nexus 6.

I have done this before for Android L but never faced this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I was able to flash the phone with custom boot.img (made img by compiling the `mkbootimg` and `unmkbootimg` binaries) but android M is behaving a little weird as even after editing default.prop the phone did not respond to the change though it had the changes.

Any idea about this ?

Comment: I think [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) is suitable for this question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with Nexus 6.
I think, I've localized this problem.

I downloaded factory image(shamu-mra58r). After flashing my Nexus 6, I tried to some change in `ramdisk`. Took stock `boot.img`, with the `unmkbootimg` got `ramdisk.cpio.gz` and kernel. If I unpacked from `ramdisk.cpio.gz` to `ramdisk.cpio` and packed back to `ramdisk.cpio.gz` and after compiled `boot.img` by `mkbootimg` - phone worked.
If I unpacked from `ramdisk.cpio.gz` to ramdisk(without any changes). Repacked to `ramdisk.cpio.gz` and after compiled `boot.img` by `mkbootimg` - phone didn't worked.

So there is problem in unpacking/repacking ramdisk. I don't know how to solve this problem.